# Multiple directives change html of single element

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 directives both placed on a single div. But only the content of the first directive is placed inside the div. Is it possible to let 2 directives change the html of this div?

```
-HTML
<div messages messageControls/>

-Messages Directive
(function() {
  "use strict";
  define(function() {
    messages = [
      function() {
        return {
          priority: 1,
          restrict: 'A',
          templateUrl: '../../messages.html',   (<p>hello world</p>)
          scope: {

          },
          link: function(scope) {}
        };
      }
    ];
    return messages;
  });

}).call(this);




-MessageControls Directive
(function() {
  "use strict";
  define(function() {
    messageControls = [
      function() {
        return {
          priority: 2,
          restrict: 'A',
          templateUrl: '../../messageControls.html',   (<p>delete message</p>)
          scope: {

          },
          link: function(scope) {}
        };
      }
    ];
    return messageControls;
  });

}).call(this);
```

When I only add one directive, it works. But when I add the second one I get the following angular error:"Multiple directives asking for template on

Comment: Can you put code here?

Comment: directives have a `priority` property you can use

Comment: have you found a solution

Comment: @OQX No, not using 2 parent directives. Using a child directive (which gets transcluded) inside a parent directive, both can have templates which is what I used