# Multiple directives appending the same element

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to have a group of directives append to the same DOM element something like this

Angular HTML

```
<div one two></div>
```

and the HTML result to be something like this

```
    <div one two>
      <h1>one</h1><!--this one added by the 'one' directive-->
      <h2>two</h2><!--this one added by the 'one' directive-->
   </div>
```

I'm not sure how is this done with directives without the need to append using Jquery

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
}).
directive('one',function(){return{restrict:'A',template:'<h1>one</h1>'};}).
directive('two',function(){return{restrict:'A',template:'<h2>two</h2>'};})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div one two></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

[similar question with no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203204/multiple-directives-change-html-of-single-element)

[Another question with no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962378/angularjs-apply-multiple-directives-same-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want with the template parameter alone.  The template parameter is just shorthand for doing something similar to the following in your directive compile function:

```
compile: function(element, attr) {
    element.empty();
    element.append(template);
}
```

If you include a template property on your directive, this will happen automatically.  If you want to override this behavior, and just have the directive append the content (without emptying it), you need to simply leave off the template property.  So your two directives would be:

```
  .directive('one', function() {
    return {
      compile: function(element, attr) {
        element.append('<h1>one</h1>');
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('two', function() {
    return {
      compile: function(element, attr) {
        element.append('<h1>two</h1>');
      }
    };
  });
```

Which you can see in operation in [this Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/VojuGHYD9DtNTiJVm52x?p=preview)

[I've also included a version that uses a template from a file](http://plnkr.co/edit/6r4tNRSaveOqSKiNJyfP?p=preview).  The only gotcha here is that loading a template in this way requires using link.

```
  .directive('three', function($http, $compile, $templateCache) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        $http.get('template.html', {cache: $templateCache}).then(function(result){
          element.append($compile(result.data)(scope));
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

And [here is a version that uses link](http://plnkr.co/edit/wMuTegg83KdG0mg4B3Pn?p=preview).

```
  .directive('one', function($compile) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.append($compile('<h1>one</h1>')(scope));
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('two', function($compile) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.append($compile('<h1>two</h1>')(scope));
      }
    };
  });
```

One think you'll notice is that the output is backwards.  It seems "one" gets appended after "two", even though it comes first in the markup.  If we added the remote version, it would work whenever the template was served remotely, but when it was delivered from the $templateCache it would also be backward.

The reason is they all have the same priority, and "link" is called in the reverse order as compile.  To fix, you can simple set the priority of one a little lower (so it get's compiled last, but linked first).

Heres [a Plunk that does this with priority](http://plnkr.co/edit/HC35ATRnsrJQptZLowWu?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two directives on the same element that will both include a template: only one of them will override the other.

One solution could be to add the `two` directive within the `one`'s template, as shown below:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
}).
directive('one',function(){return{restrict:'A',template:'<h1>one</h1><div two></div>'};}).
directive('two',function(){return{restrict:'A',template:'<h2>two</h2>'};})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div one></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Another solution, if you don't want `two` to be always part of `one`, is to simply put both next to each other in your HTML, as shown below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
}).
directive('one',function(){return{restrict:'A',template:'<h1>one</h1>'};}).
directive('two',function(){return{restrict:'A',template:'<h2>two</h2>'};})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div one></div>
    <div two></div>
  </body>

</html>
```