# Multiple directives asking for template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this might be a common problem but i havent been able to find a viable solution to the issue.

Say i have the following directive:

```
    angular.module('Api').directive('contentSpinner', function (responseInterceptor,$timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: 'js/helpers/Api/directives/content-spinner/content-spinner.html',
        scope: {
            boundRoute: '@',
            timeout: '=',
            timeoutms: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.shouldSpin = true;
            if (scope.boundRoute) {
                responseInterceptor.subScribeToRoute(scope.boundRoute, function () {
                    //Route has been completed and the spinner is ready to stop!
                    scope.shouldSpin = false;
                })
            }
            if (scope.timeout) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.shouldSpin = false;
                }, scope.timeoutms);
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Please do note the `AE` restriction.

Then i have another directive:

```
    angular.module('LBTable').directive('lbTable', ['$state', 'alertService', 'usSpinnerService', function ($state, alertService,usSpinnerService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        roles: 'all',
        templateUrl: 'js/helpers/LBTable/directives/lb-table/lb-table.html',
        scope: {
            tableData: '=',
            tableFields: '=',
            actionElement: '=',
            search: '=',
            tableDataFilter: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    }
}]);
```

As you can see both directives has a template.

Now on all of my `<lb-table>` elements i wish to add the attribute `content-spinner` (my other directive) so that it prepends the template of `contentSpinner`.

However this poses the following error:

```
 Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [contentSpinner (module: Api), lbTable] asking for template on: <lb-table
```

Which is theory makes sence it doesnt know which template to use.

However is there a way to come around this without wrapping one directive around the other like:

```
<content-spinner><lb-table></lb-table></content-spinner>
```

Comment: Can you provide a js fiddle for it? Also it wont work if you add `content-spinner` directive to 'lb-table` since both will try to create a isolated scope on the element

Comment: You can go through this. This will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28911185/3934436